# XCode 6.4: Required component for identifier "full-screen" is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, assertion

All of a sudden I started getting compilation error in xib files when compiled on XCode6.4:

```
DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderPepperIntegration/IDEInterfaceBuilderPepperIntegration-7518/InterfaceBuilder/Asset Catalog/IBICWatchSchemaProvider.m:98
Details: Required component for identifier "full-screen" is missing.
Object: <IBICWatchSchemaProvider: 0x7fda9f400480>
Required component for identifier "full-screen" is missing.
```

I have tried:

- cleaning the project
- removed derived data
- restated XCode
- rebooted machine

Comment: Where is your code? What is the question?

Comment: @osundblad: Question is how to remove that compilation error?